# Fit Constant to the Cubic, power , growth, exponential regression models

Tags: r, regression

I am very new to Statistic subject. My question is, we have ask in our class room to fit the  Cubic, power , growth, exponential regression models  with the constants whenever possible.

I have populated the graphs as below from r .

---cubic

```
Italy <- read_csv(choose.files())

Italy <- data.frame(Day = index(Italy), Italy, row.names = NULL)
glimpse(Italy)

lm(No_of_patients ~ poly(Day, degree=5), data=Italy)
ITA <- ggplot(data = Italy, aes(x = Day, y = No_of_patients))  + geom_point()
ITA + stat_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, size = 1) #cubic
```

---Power

```
Italy <- read_csv(choose.files())
Italy <- data.frame(Day = index(Italy), Italy, row.names = NULL)
ggplot(Italy,aes(x = Day,y = No_of_patients)) +  geom_point() +  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', method.args = list(start= c(a = 1,b=1)),se=FALSE)
```

---Exponential

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(quantmod)


  Italy <- read_csv(choose.files())
Italy <- data.frame(Day = index(Italy), Italy, row.names = NULL)
ggplot(Italy,aes(x = Day,y = No_of_patients)) +  geom_point() +  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ exp(x)',se=FALSE)
#summary(Italy)
```

library(growthcurver)

--Growth

```
d <- read_csv(choose.files())

gc_fit <- SummarizeGrowth(d$Day, d$No_of_patients)


gc_fit
plot(gc_fit)
```

but I dont have much idea of fitting the constant to the above model/weather the constant is needed.

and my excel sheet contains below data
[image]

With that said, appreciate a help support to tackle the question.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the constant"?  Would this be an intercept term, perhaps?  BTW, your first example is not a cubic fit at all--not even remotely. Your call to `lm` (although you don't use it) isn't a cubic model, either.  A cubic model is one in the form `y ~ 1+x+I(x^2)+I(x^3)` or, equivalently, `y ~ poly(x,3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the cubic model- I'll update it accordingly.
and yea constant refers to the intercept term.